# Run-time error 13 dismatch when CLng having text string

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I'm pretty new to excel vba and I would like to ask how can I change this code to modify H3:H7 cells (1,2,3,4,5) values to (1F, 2F, 3F, 4F, 5F) to make the macro working?
If I try to modify for example H3 cell's value to "1F" I get "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" because I guess the first code below couldn't handle text string but then how should I modify the code?

```
 returnedNumber = CLng(words(iWord, 2)) // How should I modify to handle number and text string too?
```

[Excel Sheet (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w77ng.jpg)

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim cell As Range
Dim words As Variant
Dim word As String, number As Long

words = Range("H3", Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)).Value

For Each cell In Range("J3", Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
    If FindWord(cell.Value, words, word, number) Then
        cell.Offset(, 3).Resize(, 2).Value = Array(word, number)
    End If
Next
End Sub
Function FindWord(sentence As String, words As Variant, returnedWord As String, returnedNumber As Long) As Boolean
Dim iWord As Long
Dim word As String

For iWord = LBound(words, 1) To UBound(words, 1)
    word = CStr(words(iWord, 1))
    If InStr(sentence, word) Then
        FindWord = True
        returnedWord = word
        returnedNumber = CLng(words(iWord, 2))
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow the values to be text such as `"1F"`, you need to

- Change `returnedNumber As Long` to be `returnedNumber As String`, and
- Change `CLng(words(iWord, 2))` to be `CStr(words(iWord, 2))`
- Change `number As Long` to be `number As String`

Comment: Thank you so much! It was helpful, I've changed "Dim number As Long" to "Dim number As String" aswell and now it works! Have a nice day!

Comment: @GálTamás - well spotted - I had overlooked that one.